# How to add space between ouputs of the same chunk in R?

Tags: r, spacing

I have the following code in R

```
{r echo=F }

listA <- list(knitr::kable(mtcars[1:4,1:4]),knitr::kable(mtcars[1:4,1:4]),knitr::kable(mtcars[1:4,1:4]))

listA[[1]]
listA[[2]]
listA[[3]]
```

¿How can I increase the blank space between the three resulting tables without putting them in different chunks and considering that they are supposed to be part of an html document using bookdown and prettydoc?

Answer (score 0):

For normal RMarkdown docs this workaround is ok:

```
{r echo=F, results='asis'}

listA <- list(knitr::kable(mtcars[1:4,1:4]),knitr::kable(mtcars[1:4,1:4]),knitr::kable(mtcars[1:4,1:4]))


listA[[1]]
cat("\n")
cat("#####\n")
cat("\n")
listA[[2]]  
listA[[3]]
```

For anything more complicated, like using bookdown + prettydocs, this solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks!, but I meant blank spacing (edited question accordingly).

Comment: If you render this example to html or pdf they are blank spaces between Table 1 and Table 2 (even though it looks like #### in markdown). You also need `results='asis'` in your chunk header for this to work.

Comment: Sorry! i was too fast and missed the modification on the chunk options. However I am rendering an html using bookdown and prettydoc, and your solution renders a numbering between the tables as if they were subsections of the section where the tables are supposed to be displayed within the document.

Comment: No worries. Please update your question to include that you're using bookdown and prettydoc

Comment: Done. Thanks for your input in any case!